C Link sqlite3 to Visual Studio
I linked sqlite to Visual Studio, but when I use the API of sqlite, it tells me -> Error LNK2001 "API"
I seted
#include "sqlite3.h"
sqlite3.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)
%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)`

What should I do next?

What did you try exactly?? How can you set those lines directly in code, or in the compiler options?

yeah i set those compiler options and include sqlite3.h
